# The upper bound on a Nondeterministic Finite Automata's configurations number

Tags: finite-automata, parsers, upper-bound

In **"Engineering: A Compiler"** 2nd ed. by Cooper and Torczon,
in **2.4.1 "Nondeterministic Finite Automata"** of Chapter 2,
section **"Equivalence of NFAs and DFAs"**

discusses the upper bound of a NFA's configurations number.

Here

- NFA stands for Nondeterministic Finite Automata
- DFA stands for Deterministic Finite Automata

NFA is a  is a five-tuple $(S, \Sigma, \delta, s_0 , S_A)$, where

- $S$ is the finite set of states in the recognizer, along with an error state $s_e$.
- $\Sigma$ is the finite alphabet used by the FA. Typically, $\Sigma$ is the union
  of the edge labels in the transition diagram.
- $\delta(s,c)$ is the FA's transition function. It maps each state $s ∈ S$
  and each character $c \in \Sigma$ into some next state. In state $s_i$ with input
  character $c$, the FA takes the transition $s_i \xrightarrow{\text{c}}\delta(s_i ,c)$.
- $s_0 \in S$ is the designated start state.
- $S_A$ is the set of accepting states, $S_A \subseteq S$.

A **configuration** of a NFA is defined as follows

> Each time the NFA must make a nondeterministic choice, the NFA clones
>   itself to pursue each possible transition. Thus, for a given input
>   character, the NFA is in a specific set of states, taken across all of
>   its clones.
>
> In this model, the NFA pursues all paths concurrently. At
>   any point, we call the specific set of states in which the NFA is
>   active its **configuration**.
>
> When the NFA reaches a configuration in
>   which it has exhausted the input and one or
>   more of the clones has reached an accepting state, the NFA accepts the
>   string.

Given the definitions above, the books states

> Consider the state of an NFA when it has reached some point in the
>   input string. [...] the NFA has some
>   finite set of operating clones.
>
> The number of these configurations can be bounded;
>
> for each state, the configuration either includes one or
>   more clones in that state or it does not. Thus, an NFA with $n$ states
>   produces at most $\lvert\Sigma\rvert^n$ configurations.

**My question.**

*Please explain in as much details as possible, how $\lvert\Sigma\rvert^n$ is derived.*

I need help, because while trying to follow the book's reasoning, I get lost right after this sentence

> for each state, the configuration either includes one or
>   more clones in that state or it does not.

This sounds like the upper bound on the number of configurations should be $2^n$, but instead the book gives $\lvert\Sigma\rvert^n$ bringing in $\Sigma$ seemingly out of the blue.

Comment: You're right; the book's wrong.

Comment: @RickDecker Thanks for the comment. Maybe post it as an answer? So I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that:
We can view a nondeterministic computation as a directed acyclic graph of configurations indexed by time.

I have a guess that in your eyes:
$2^n$ for both, one directs itself and one directs others and *at most* every has the $\Sigma$ chance to go next state, maybe to itself, maybe the other state, so from $1$ to $n$ state, an NFA produces at most $\mid\Sigma\mid^n$ configurations.

Here are more details: http://www.cse.msu.edu/~torng/360Book/NFA/

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction. Could you expand a bit your answer? I cannot get how you derive the last step, and that is the crux of the question, to state it simply.